# La différence phonétique entre "Anne", "an" et "âne"

Tags: phonétique, nasalisation, son

Quelle est la différence de prononciation entre le prénom *Anne* et le nom d'animal *âne* ? J'ai inclus *an* pour comparaison avec *Anne* - à mon avis il s'agit du même [a], mais nasalisé dans *an*, alors que dans *âne* on a un son ouvert différent.

**Un peu du contexte:** je n'ai jamais fait attention aux différents types de "a" en français, qui me semble  poser moins de problèmes (aux locuteurs de langues slaves) que les variations entre les "e" (ouvert, fermé ou shwa) , "u/ou" ou les sons nasalisés vs. non-nasalisés. Néanmoins, un ami francophone m'a affirmé récemment que dans le cas de *Anne* et *âne* il s'agit d'une différence phonétiquement significative.

Answer (score 5):

Je prononce les *âne* et *Anne* exactement de la même façon, et il me semble que c'est la même chose pour la très grande majorité des locuteurs en France, si ce n'est tous, contrairement au [Québec](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/52455/1109) où j'entends /awn/ pour l'animal (similaire à la fin du mot *down* en anglais).

Même quand ils sont prononcés de la même façon, le contexte fait qu'il est peu probable qu'on les confonde.

Ce peut aussi être simplement la présence ou non d'un article (ex: pour Anne, pour l'âne) ou l'accord masculin / féminin (le petit âne / la petite Anne).

Answer (score 3):

Je ne peux pas vraiment me prononcer sur les concepts, mais ça dépend aussi de quel locuteur il s'agit. Au Québec, les deux sont complètement différents (voire les trois : [*an*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/an#Prononciation) \ã\ et pas exactement [ɑ̃]). Pour s'en convaincre on peut écouter la prononciation du mot [*panne*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/panne#Prononciation) (pour *Anne*), commune (mais effectivement pas dans le cas des [toponymes](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/52452/la-diff%c3%a9rence-phon%c3%a9tique-entre-anne-an-et-%c3%a2ne/52455?noredirect=1#comment108771_52455) composés...), et celle de [*âne*](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Un_%C3%A2ne.ogg?uselang=fr) au Québec, fort différente !

Comment: https://forumdupeuple.com/index.php?topic=162.0

Comment: @jlliagre C'est vrai, dans les toponymes composés on prononce comme âne au Québec mais pas avec le prénom tout court. Quoique avec _Anne-Marie_ j'ai déjà entendu comme _âne_ aussi. Mais avec _Anne_ seul, jamais.

Answer (score 3):

Historiquement (il y a 50 ans ?) le Français prononçait différemment *Anne* et *âne*, *brin* et *brun*, *haute* et *hotte*, *été* et *était*. C’était enseigné en primaire, mais pas partout : certaines régions n’ont jamais fait la différence.
Ces différences s’estompent ainsi que le constate [Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prononciation_du_fran%C3%A7ais).

Le TLFi, comme la majorité des dictionnaires, marque la différence entre *mâle*  [mɑ:l] et *mal*  [mal]
[TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/m%C3%A2le)

Edit suite à réponse de jlliagre

Il est difficile d’être précis ; j’avoue que je ne peux ne pas l’être.

Il existe un site intéressant qui relève et illustre les différences de prononciation constatées selon les régions en France, Belgique et Suisse.
https://francaisdenosregions.com/2017/07/06/ces-mots-qui-ne-se-prononcent-pas-de-la-meme-facon-dun-bout-a-lautre-de-la-france/

Ce site donne entre autres une carte de la différenciation, avant la guerre, entre « brin » « brun » en fonction de la région.

En 1941, André Martinet, alors prisonnier dans un camp en Allemagne, propose à ses codétenus de répondre à une série de questions quant à leurs habitudes de prononciation en français (45 questions, 409 répondants).
On peut lire des extraits détaillés (l’auteur avait le temps, il était en oflag pour 4 ans).
[Extraits du livre de Martinet](https://books.google.be/books?id=uwY9zivQzIAC&pg=PA247&hl=fr&source=gbs_selected_pages&cad=2#v=onepage&q&f=false)

J’avoue déplorer que de plus en plus de professionnels de la télévision prononcent "été" et "était" de la même façon.

Comment: Il semble qu'il y a cinquante ans, *âne* et *Anne* étaient déjà prononcés de manière identique par une grande partie des français, alors que la distinction *pâte* / *patte* ou *mâle* / *mal* était encore souvent marquée. La prononciation d'âne avec un [ɑ:] postérieur long n'apparaît plus dans les dictionnaires dès le début du XXe siècle alors que celle de *pâte* ou *mâle* a subsisté. Pour *brin* et *brun*, toutes les régions faisaient la différence et certaines continuent à la faire.